# Opening a pdf file in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I am using the following piece of code to open a PDF file that I have just created this methods works in one section on my site but it does not seem to redirect to the PDF from another section of my site. What could possible be the reason why the PDF  file is not opening.

```
Context.Response.Buffer = false;
FileStream inStr = null;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
long byteCount;
inStr = File.OpenRead(pdfPath);
while ((byteCount = inStr.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
    if (Context.Response.IsClientConnected) {
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        Context.Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting any exception? what's message?

Comment: why won't you let the browser handle the file ? it will open it in a plugin if available or it will prompt for download.

Comment: no there was no error that is what is making this so difficult to debug.

Comment: how would I let the browser handle it?

Comment: Look at this post and try it that way:  http://forums.asp.net/t/1219837.aspx

Comment: Instead of opening the file and writing it yourself to the stream (inefficient) use response.Transmit file - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Also put a breakpoint right on the while statement, and look at the pdfPath is it a full disk path to the file, does it exist there?

Comment: If you choose to stick with this type of code (and not replace with response.TransmitFile) you want to get rid of the Flush call, you are making the writes extremely ineffecient, ASP.NET takes care of flushing for you, and very rarely if ever you want to force a flush. Naively you would think the download will go faster, but practically it will start marginally faster, and end a lot later.

Comment: If you've got a path to the file, can't you just let the user download it by clicking on a link? (Assign that path to a hyperlink control and you go to one line of code...) Also check your MIME types in IIS if you have control of the server. I've seen cases where if it's not set up properly in the folder, you won't get an error but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your pdf path is relative. 
You could also read the file in one shot 
bytez=File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(pdfPath))

And send it the same way. Response.BinaryWrite(bytez).

Comment: Reading the pdf in memory is highly not recommended in a web site. What will happen (depending on size of PDF and number of concurrent requests of course) is that you will a high chance of running out of memory.